# GDB question - how do I go through disassembled code line by line?

Tags: gdb, disassembly

I'd like to go through a binary file my teacher gave me line by line to check addresses on the stack and the contents of different registers, but I'm not extremely familiar with using gdb. Although I have the C code, we're supposed to work entirely from a binary file. Here are the commands I've used so far:

```
(gdb) file SomeCode
```

Which gives me this message:

```
Reading symbols from ../overflow/SomeCode ...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Then I use :

```
(gdb) disas main
```

which gives me all of the assembly. I wanted to set up a break point and use the "next" command, but none of the commands I tried work. Does anyone know the syntax I would use?

Answer (score 3):

try using `ni` which is `nexti`.  equivalent is `si` which is step instruction

Comment: when I try just ni, next, step, etc after the "file SomeCode" command or after "disas main" it says "the program is not being run". If I try to do "run ./SomeCode" it says permission denied. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @user first set break point, run, next: `break main`, `run`, `stepi`.  read manual, it explains pretty well.  I do not mean to put you off, manual is really excellent source to learn debugging.  also, you can use help command , example, `help break`

Comment: @user if you are still struggling, post your commands, I will point out where you make the missstake.

Comment: I recompiled from the C file and it seems to be working now. I think the binary file my teacher gave me wasn't compiled with the -g switch. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 2):

nexti if you want to jump over function calls. 
stepi if you want to enter a function call.

The following documentation is very helpful; it has a list of all the important commands you could use on gdb.

X86-64: http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/docs/gdbnotes-x86-64.pdf

IA32: http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/docs/gdbnotes-ia32.pdf